# Get Scroll position after Div is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scroll-position

I have a webpage that has a floating div in it which follows the user as the page scrolls.

the page is made up of other divs that can be expanded and hidden using jquery slideToggle functionality.

the problem is when i hide a div, the scroll bar moves down the page as the div is hidden instead of staying at the top of the page. any idea why this is happening?

Code for the Scroll:

```
var scrollPos;

    $().ready(function () {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#FloatingClaimToolBar");

        $(window).scroll(function () {

            var top = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop;
            // global var
            scrollPos = top;

            $scrollingDiv
            .stop()
            .animate({ "marginTop": (top - 15) + "px" }, 0);
        });
    });
```

After the div is hidden i call this method with the intention of positioning the floating div back to the top of the page but it doesn't work:

```
function AdjustToolBar(divID) {

            var $scrollingDiv = $("#FloatingClaimToolBar");

            $scrollingDiv
            .stop()
            .animate({ "marginTop": (window.scrollPos-15) + "px" }, 0);          
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after the div is hidden"? Do you "hide" it by using `display:none`  respectively `.hide()`? If so, you can't position it when taken it out of the DOM and it will no longer be part of the layout. Better use `visibility:hidden` (opacity) instead. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: No you got me correct! I will give that a go.